# update datatype field int to decimal128 in mongo db in nested json structure

Tags: mongodb, query, update, mongodb-4.0

Hi have tried to updated nested field datatype

```
    db.test.find().forEach(function(data){
data.age = NumberDecimal(data.age);
data.phone.$.mob = NumberDecimal(data.phone.$.mob);
db.test.updateOne({_id:data._id}, {$set:{age:data.age},{phone.$.mob:data.phone.$.mob}})
})
```

the above query I tried to run but not able to update data type

Document Structure is

```
{
_id: (objectId)
"lastname":"test",
"age":25(int),
"phone":[
0:{
"_id":(objectId),
"mob":9000112 (int)
},
1:{
"_id":(objectId),
"mob":88909 (int)
},
2:{
"_id":(objectId),
"mob":88909 (int)
}
]
}
```

Need to update every int field to decimal128 datatype
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
   [
      {
         $set: {
            age: { $toDecimal: "$age" },
            phone: {
               $map: {
                  input: "$phone",
                  in: { $mergeObjects: ["$$this", { mob: { $toDecimal: "$$this.mob" } }] }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

Comment: thanks it is working, one more question inside phone again I am having one more array but without id and then how we can update field type for that scenario suppose                                       {
    "phone" : [
        {
            "mob" : 1, (int)
            "contacts" : [
                { "address" : "some address 1" },
                { "address" : "some address 3" }
            ]
        }
    ]
} how can I update datatype for address

Comment: You need to nest another `$map`. Be aware, the default variable is `this`, use a different name for nested $map.

Comment: Hi https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/32815/wernfried-domscheit I have written the query and that is working fine but I have some object outside that same array that Object is got deleted

Comment: Can you provide an example? Because of `$mergeObjects: ["$$this", ...` it should not remove anything.

Comment: db.collection.updateMany({},
   [
      {
         $set: {
            
            phone: {
               $map: {
                  input: "$phone",
                  as:"p",
    in:{address:{$map:{input:"$$p.phone",in:{$mergeObjects:["$this",{telephone:{$toDecimal:"$$this.telephone"}}]}}}}
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
)

Comment: Json struct is look like,{ 
  "phone" : [   
       test:{
   testid:1,
   testname:"test"
   }
                     address:[{ "firstName" : "John",  
                       "lastName"  : "Doe",
                       "telephone"       : 23 }]
       test2:{
   testid:2,
   testname:"test2"
   }
                 ],                            
  "phone"      : [ 
         test:{
 testid:3,
 testname:"test"
}
          address:[{ "firstName" : "test",  
         "lastName"  : "test",
        "telephone"       : 23 }]
 test2:{
 testid:2,
 testname:"test2"}
 ] 
}

Comment: That's a completely different document structure. Please open a separate question for it.